# What is the fastest way to find the maximum of an array and another variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

I have a list `x` and another variable `y`. I want to find the maximum of all the elements from `x` and `y` combined. Which of these runs fastest?

1. `max(*x, y)`
2. `max(max(x), y)`
3. `max(x+[y])`
4. First find `k=max(x)` and then find maximum of `k` and `y` using *if else* statement

Here's the code and `timeit` results:

```
import timeit

setup_="""\
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = 6
"""

s="""\
max(*x, y)
"""
print(timeit.timeit(setup=setup_, stmt=s))

x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = 6
s="""\
max(max(x), y)
"""
print(timeit.timeit(setup=setup_, stmt=s))

x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = 6
s="""\
max(x+[y])
"""
print(timeit.timeit(setup=setup_, stmt=s))


x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = 6
s="""\
k=max(x)
if k>=y:
    max_ = k
else:
    max_ = y
"""
print(timeit.timeit(setup=setup_, stmt=s))
```

```
0.5596736
0.4779417
0.5439717
0.3297147
```

Are there any faster ways than the above methods?

Comment: Please update your question with the results of your tests with ‘timeit’.

Comment: I have updated as requested.

Comment: @DeepBodra "x = [1,2,3,4,5]; y = 6" should be move to the `setup` argument since they are not the interesting statements to be measured.

Comment: @GZ0 Yeah! Updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best method could be found out by implementing the [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) python.

I am giving out the timing for each of your program, and you will see which one is best

```
import timeit

# Taking x = [1,2,3,4,5] and y = 8
print(timeit.timeit('max([1,2,3,4,5], [8])', number=10000))
print(timeit.timeit('max(max([1,2,3,4,5]), 8)', number=10000))
print(timeit.timeit('max([1,2,3,4,5]+[8])', number=10000))

Output

0.003129853866994381                                                                                                                   
0.0323555301874876                                                                                                                     
0.007466199807822704
```

Your first idea is the best one `max(x, [y])`. 4th point is equivalent to the second point hence it was not taken into consideration. Hope that helps.

Comment: you should probably use a larger list (e.g. of 50 elements) and use `min(timeit.repeat(...))` to take care of possible noises, at least in my practice it was more representative

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it. Logically 2nd and 4th options are same but the code for these two options are different and as a result 2nd one is better than the 4th one.

Comment: No problem @DeepBodra. Makes sense though, however, previous representation of your code gave me the same sense, hence I did not take it into consideration.

Comment: Note that `max([1,2,3,4,5], [8])` is different from the rest. It compares two lists instead.

Comment: @GZ0 I just realized that since I got a wrong answer in one of the testcases.

Comment: You need `max(*[1,2,3,4,5], 8)` instead.